# Jasmine Angular : How to write unit test for anonymous func given as args

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

```
public listenCloseEvt() {
    this.renderer.listen(window, 'close', () => {
      this.showModal = false;
    });
}
```

I am able to `spyOn` `render.listen` but I am unable to reach `this.showModal` false line on writing unit test.

Answer (score 0):

If you spy on something the implementation details are lost for that object.

To get to the implementation you'll have to `callThrough()` to the original implementation on your spy.

Instead of:

`spyOn(renderer.listen)`

use

`spyOn(renderer.listen).and.callThrough()`